# Weird Div Positioning

Tags: css

I created three DIVs that I wanted to appear from left to right.

```
<div id="middle">
     <div id="middleleft"></div>
     <div id="middleleftopenclose"></div>
     <div id="middleright"></div>
</div>
```

However, DIV *middleleftopenclose* appears all the way on the left and not after *middleleft*. Why is that?

```
#middle {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
#middleleft {
    width: 445px;
    float: left;
}
#middleleftopenclose {
    background-color:#2a2729;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 15px;
    float: left;
}
#middleright {
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 460px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: float doesn't work with `position: absolute`. Try changing it to `position: relative`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Float doesn't work with `position: absolute.` Try changing it to `position: relative;`

```
#middleleft {
    width: 445px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#middleleftopenclose {
    background-color:#2a2729;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 15px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the floats and use display: inline-block;

Comment: Hmm, doesn't work [Here's the page itself](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/NewMaps/Map.php)

Comment: I don't understand it seems to be functioning fine?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the browser is not able to accommodate all the divs horizontally, i.e., the sum of widths of the divs is more the page width. Try changing the div widths.

Comment: I only take up 460px and the rest is set to 100%. [Here's the page itself](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/NewMaps/Map.php)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, you can't use `position: absolute` together with `float`. Changing it to `position: relative` should fix most of it. I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XJ68G/) to visualize it. I added some colours to make it more obvious, and I also set the `#middleleft` to `height: 100%`, otherwise they wouldn't float correctly. I don't know if this applies to your site out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#middle { width: 100% }
#middle div { display: inline-block; width: 33%; }
```

You don't need float or position relative or position absolute :)